# How to generate random characters from only 'A', 'B', 'S' and 'Z' in C?

Tags: c

This code generates random characters from 'A' to 'Z' but I need to generate random characters from only 'A', 'B', 'S' and 'Z' characters. Please help.

```
int main (void)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    char random;

    random = (rand() % 26) + 'A';

    printf ("Random: %c\n", random);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just pick a random number between 0 and 3 and then map this number to your characters with a `switch` statement.

Comment: @MartinZabel An array of four characters will work better..

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, you are right. That is more elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a string literal, e.g. `"ABSZ"` can be used like an array of `char`, you can choose a random character from a set of allowed characters with code like this

```
random = "ABSZ"[rand()%4];
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a string with the allowed characters;

select a random number from `0` to the `number of characters - 1` (c arrays starts from zero);

finally pick the random selected character from the string accessing it as an array

(strings are arrays of characters)

```
int main (void)
{
    char *characters="ABSZ";
    int  whichOne;

    srand(time(NULL));

    whichOne = rand() % 4; // 0..3

    printf ("Random: %c\n", characters[whichOne]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35443306/2410359) good answer is far too simple, portable, understandable and useful.

How about some obfuscation?

```
int rand ABSZ(void) {
  int x = rand()%4;
  return ((x*-13 + 63)*x + -47)*x/3 + 'A';
}
```

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Just a bit of fun, user3386109 answer is just fine.